# How to record proof of contract exploit on-chain?

Tags: security, dapp-design, insurance

Suppose one want to insure from certain contract hacks. Do do that in non custodial manner, we need some way to detect hack on-chain.

I see some obvious ideas, like "if one wallet stores more than x% of tokens (which supposed to be distributed) => hack happened". Or for price oracle dependent contract "if there was sudden price move departing x% from slide average => hack happened". But I am not sure if that covers all possible use cases.

So is there any known implementation for such Proof-of-Hack? Or maybe there is some known attack which could not be covered by on-chain logic?